# While loop not running?

Tags: java

I am working on a java problem at the moment where I am creating a program that simulates the old TV quiz show, You Bet Your Life. The game show host, Groucho Marx, chooses a secret word, then chats with the contestants for a while. If either contestant uses the secret word in a sentence, he or she wins $100.00.

My program is meant to check for this secret word.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

    public class Groucho{
      String secret; 

        Groucho(String secret){
        this.secret = secret; 
      }

      public String saysSecret(String line){
        if(secret.equals(line)){
         return("You have won $100! The secret word is: " + secret);
        }
        else{
          return("false");
        }
      }

      public void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String line = in.nextLine();
        Groucho g = new Groucho(line);

      while (in.hasNextLine()) {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          String guess = input.nextLine();
          saysSecret(guess);

        }
      }  
    }
```

I thought his should work but when I run it I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong? 
Many thanks!
Miles

Answer (score 6):

Add the `static` keyword to the `main` method so that the application has a valid entry point

As `saySecret` is an instance method, it needs to be invoked as such, replace

```
saysSecret(guess);
```

with

```
g.saysSecret(guess);
```

Comment: Must be a DrJava thing.  You'd get a different exception if it were run from the command line.

Comment: Yes, you can see from its trace its trying to do its reflection magic

Comment: When I include static in the main it says:
non-static method saysSecret(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context

Appreciate the help!

Comment: all methods called from main method have to be static, and class fields also

Comment: You have to use g.saysSecret(guess)
public void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String line = in.nextLine();
        Groucho g = new Groucho(line);

      while (in.hasNextLine()) {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          String guess = input.nextLine();
          g.saysSecret(guess);

        }
      }

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to change your `while` loop to something like this:

```
while (in.hasNextLine()) {
    String guess = in.nextLine();
    String answer = g.saysSecret(guess);
    System.out.println(answer);
}
```

No need to create a new `Scanner` each time. Also, you have to call `saysSecret` on the `g` instance, as it is not static. Finally, the `saysSecret` method only returns an answer, but you still need to print it.

However, this will still loop forever, waiting for user input. It would be better to modify your `saysSecret` method to return a boolean and exit the loop once this boolean is true, i.e., the guess was correct.